# PHP multiple file upload that allows empty fields

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm in the process of learning file uploading and PHP, so apologies if I can't describe myself properly.

I'm trying to create a form for uploading up to 5 images. My problem is a logical operator that wouldn't necessitate 4th or 5th image. Currently if I upload 4 images, the program stops uploading at the 3rd image.

```
if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file.".".$image1FileType)
      && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2.".".$image2FileType)
      && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image3"]["tmp_name"], $target_file3.".".$image3FileType))
      || move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image4"]["tmp_name"], $target_file4.".".$image4FileType)
      || move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image5"]["tmp_name"], $target_file5.".".$image5FileType)
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't upload your files like this. Instead, iterate through them with a `for` or `foreach` loop and upload them one by one if they are not empty.

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
        // File is empty so continue with the next file
        continue;
    }

    $nameArray = explode('.', $file['name']);
    $type = end($nameArray);
    $target_file = 'You name it how you want it';

    if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_file . '.' . $type)) {
        echo 'File ' . $file['name'] . ' couldn\'t be uploaded<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply but i have another question, where is the part that uploads the files& How i understand this, if move file is false it gives and error, but how does it upload in case fir condition is  false?

Comment: The upload happens in the if statement with this line: `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_file . '.' . $type)`. If the error doesn't show up, it means the file is uploaded. If you read the documentation of `move_uploaded_file` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) then you can see that `move_uploaded_file` function returns a boolean. False, if the upload was unsuccessful - and therefor the upload didn't happen - and True if the upload was successful. What I did in the `if` statement was that I'm only catching the error :)